# google.visualization.ControlWrapper not mixing well with bootstrap?

Tags: google-visualization, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 for layout and found whether to put google.visualization.ControlWrapper under bootstrap container or not gives very different behavior. Two examples:

1. with NumberRangerFilter:

   - Outside of container looks like:
     [image]
   - Inside of container looks like:
     [image]

---

2. with CategoryFilter:

   - Outside of container looks like:
     [image]
   - Inside of container looks like:
     [image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to stem from the fact outer div was styled as "display:none" at the onset,  so computed width and height don't have the correct starting values. refining the div as "visibility: hidden" solved the issue